# What should be the accepted answer when new details are added to the original question and change the nature of the problem?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I asked a question in the main forum, and I for clarity purposes I provided a simplification of my code.

There was an answer that solved it and worked fine for me, but in the comments I provided more details about my code. With this new information there was another answer that was a better fit for my problem, but did not address the original question since this was asked based on a simplification of my code.

I think both answers might be useful for people with the same issue I had, but they address two different problems. I feel that if I accept the new answer which worked better for me it will not match the original question and it might be confusing for people reading the post in the future. It is also true that I ended using that solution. What is the best way to proceed?

Comment: You better edit the question to include the extra info you gave in the comments. Accept the answer that helped you most. We can't help you with that. It is up to you. Once you are > 60 rep you can offer a bounty (will cost you 50 rep) to award the other answer if you feel to it, otherwise an simple upvote is all there is.

Comment: It's best **not** to ask a question and then shift requirements after it has been answered. If the question as originally stated has been answered, and you have a new problem, then ask a new question.

Comment: As the preferred, but currently unaccepted answer was mine, _[question here for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57334582)_, and the additional information from the comments was 100% unrelated to the problem or my solution, _(although used for completeness)_, there is no good reason not to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in batch, but I think that both answers directly address your question and can stand on their own without the comment you've made. As both answers received upvotes it seems they are both valid solutions to the problem described. Accept whatever helped *you the most*.

> I think both answers might be useful for people with the same issue I had

Future visitors can upvote the answer that helped them. Through that, the most upvoted and thus best answer floats to the top, thats how SO works. The green tick just indicates what helped you, thats your personal choice.

Comment: I agree with, "Accept whatever helped you the most", and based upon your comment, @j.xavier.atero, "it works! this approach it's a better fit for my specific problem and I will use it.", it's clear that you should change your vote in this instance.

Comment: “the most upvoted and thus best answer floats to the top” — except that the one with the green tick mark is pinned to the top, and will be there even if other answers have many more upvotes.

Comment: @crisLuengo yes, I consider that a logical flaw, and there is already an ongoing debate if that should be changed. I personally look at the most upvoted answer and ignore the OPs accepted mark.

Comment: I ignore the green tick too. I read through all answers, I learn more that way.

Answer (score -8):

1. Don't change your question essentially. If the changes of the question make it to an essentially new question, ask a new question.
2. You can change your accept vote only once (except if the accepted answer gets somehow deleted, what is a rare event). Better if you do even that only rarely - no one likes to lose the +15 for his hard work. If you already given an accept, don't change it only because a newer answer is a little bit better.
3. Don't try to pack two problems into a single question:

   1. You will get answers mostly from those who can answer both (although partial answers are allowed, no one likes to write them)
   2. You risk the closure of your question as "too broad".
   3. You will want the answerers to solve multiple problems for a single reward.
   4. Future visitors having only one of your problems will find a lesser concentrated information source (and some present voters are sensitive for that).
4. If new details (or history) make your old question obsolete, best if you let it as is. You might mention it as a footnote or comment below your question. So: "*(Note, Oracle 17.2.3 can already do this with neural network queries, this problem is for Oracle 12 in 2019.)*" On this way, althought the content won't be uptodate, it will be still useful in the future for people using still Oracle 12.
5. Note: asking multiple questions makes you responsible for both. You will need to take care them, react comments/answers/improvement suggestions and so on. Taking care a question is typically more work, than writing an answer.
6. Best if you wait at least a day with your accept vote. Leave open the possibility that a yet better answer arrives.

At least, it would be the theory.

Practice is that the community treats questions often unfairly, thus asking even a single question might be stressy. For that problem, there is no easy solution. Experience can help you to work around this problem.

Comment: Hmm... seems like a reasonable answer, but it seems to have pissed some people off. I'm guessing it's because of the sentence *Practice is that the community treats questions often unfairly,...*

Comment: @JamesKPolk: I agree. I see that Peter H often makes some very intelligent insightful observations on the dynamics of the site, but then injects emotional and argumentative pokes that detract from the nuggets of quality that are present.

Comment: Thanks. Ok, but if I don't mention that the community treats questions often unfairly, I can make the false belief in the OP, that the likely downvote/closure of his following questions had been his fault. What if he follows these all, and then gets a downvoted + closed question + a Q-ban? It will be my fault from that point, at least on a moral level. Similars happened to me already: once I suggested someone to re-ask his question on site X, because it matches its topic better. He did, and... it was closed on a... well, dubious reason.

Comment: @peterh the lesson there being that unless you are active on the target site, are well acquainted with the topicality of said site, and you're absolutely certain that the question would be accepted on the target site, you should not suggest that someone re-ask their question there. It's one thing to say the question is off-topic here as someone who is active here and who understands the topicality, etc. It's an entirely different thing to say the questions is on-topic somewhere else when you don't have those experience necessary to determine that.

Comment: @TinyGiant No. The lesson here that any time I give an advice how to/where to post, I also warn him, that beware, there might be "surprises".

Comment: @peterh then you got the wrong lesson out of it.

Comment: @TinyGiant Maybe I am only not evil.